# Why can't I apply margin to my H1 element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, heading

I am trying to make my `h1` text not squished to the left. I am also using bootstrap so I'm not sure if that effects anything:

```css
h1 {
    margin: 5px 40px 10px 70px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 
    <head>
   
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d712ea1844.js"></script>
   
   
    <title>About Mike</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/a1.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
    </head>
   
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About Mike</a>
                </div>
 
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="../index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                        <li><a href="artifact1/ArtifactPage1.html">Artifact 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../artifact2/ArtifactPage2.html">Artifact 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
               
        
            <h1 id="annoyingtitle">Examples of Work</h1>
            <p id="p0">This is an example of a paper I wrote while I attended Frankline Pierce University.  In this paper I look at the lenses at which mental illness is viewed in different parts of the world.</p>
    <br/>
        
        <A id="mentallink" HREF="mentalillness.docx">Mental Illness Cultural Lenses and Barriers</A>
        
    <br/>
    
        
    <p id="p1"> Reflection: Writing this essay was easily one of my hardest assignments I have ever done.  It involved levels of research that I hadn’t done before.  I learned how to form an argument while drawing evidence from multiple sources.  This has helped me in my research and writing skills.  My favorite part of writing this paper was doing the research.  On this assignment we were allowed to pull sources from almost anywhere as long as they were credible,  I enjoyed being able to go as far as my mind could take me.  The one risk I believe I took with this project was the structure and flow.  The entire assignment was 9 pages long. This made my biggest problem getting it all to flow together and getting my ideas in the right order.  If I could re-do this assignment I wish I would write a better conclusion to the paper.    </p>
    <br/>
 
    <div id="annoying">
        <ul id="list1" class="text-center list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-md-4"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <br>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/m">@M</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <br>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mike">mike</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <br>
                <a href="email@email.com">email@email.com</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why can't you? I copied your code and the margin works

Comment: Is there other CSS involved?

Comment: There is no other CSS involved.  I feel like it has to be something else with my HTML file.  I'm really lost lol.

Comment: Make sure you are saving the file, refreshing your browser, maybe clearing your cache, close your browser and reopen, do the same for your text editor, etc.  Your code does work.  Check out: https://jsfiddle.net/charlwillia6/gb23ct2u/3/

Make sure the URL is correct, etc., or post your entire code.  If there are other CSS styles that are messing with your h1 element, it isn't relevant in your question.

Comment: I tried all the above and still nothing.  I posted my HTML.  I appreciate all your guys help.

Comment: @Mik3y ~ Even the updated code you posted in your edit works.  Again, try clearing all your caches, make sure that the files are saved.  I am assuming that the only style in the `a1.css` file that is linked is the h1 style you have posted.  If not, then post what is in your `a1.css` file also. https://jsfiddle.net/charlwillia6/gb23ct2u/5/

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  I can see that it works in JSFiddle but I have no idea why my preview in google chrome will not show it.  I have cleared cache on both programs.

Comment: Make sure the local URL is correct in your browser, etc., Try a different browser. There either has to be an element that doesn't have a closed tag, another CSS file that is overriding your h1 elements, or something that you have not posted that is conflicting with your styles.

Answer (score 1):

Your margin is working. You want your h1 not squished to the left? How about horizontally centered? (I usually put margin bottom on headers though)

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: For some reason my h1 still doesn't move at all.  I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.  Is there possibly something else in the HTML thats messing it up?

Comment: How should we know, edit your answer and post your full HTML

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are saving the file, refreshing your browser, maybe clearing your cache, close your browser and re-open, do the same for your text editor, etc.  Your code does work.

Make sure the local URL is correct in your browser, etc., or post your entire code.  Try a different browser. There either has to be an element that doesn't have a closed tag, another CSS file that is overriding your h1 elements, or something that you have not posted that is conflicting with your styles.